# Error: The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: entity-framework, c#-3.0

Good day to all.

Im Having Entity or complex type cannot be encountered This is the first time i encountered this type of error Someone Help me

```
public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
{ 
    IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;

    IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;




    if (applicantdata == null)
    {

        var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
                             join app in context.APPLICANTs 
                             on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
                            where app.APPLICANT_LogicalDelete == false
                            select new APPLICANT()
                             {
           APPLICANT_LastName = a.Applicant_LASTNAME,
           APPLICANT_FirstName = a.Applicant_FIRSTNAME,
           APPLICANT_MiddleName = a.Applicant_MIDDLENAME,
           APPLICANT_Address = a.Applicant_ADDRESS,
           APPLICANT_City = a.Applicant_CITY,
           APPLICANT_Phone = a.Applicant_PHONE,
            APPLICANT_Email= a.Applicant_EMAIL
       });

        applicantdata = applicantList.Where(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.APPLICANT_LastName)).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();

        if (applicantdata.Any())    
        {
            Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
        }
    }
    return applicantdata.ToList().Take(1000);

}
```

And This is the line where i encounter the error Thanks!

```
applicantdata = applicantList.Where(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.APPLICANT_LastName)).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
```

AND THE ERROR IN THE LINE ABOVE IS

System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'Model.APPLICANT' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your query is constructing objects of type registerd as entity type. You don't need to initalize such objects with select new{...}.

Try to change your query like this:

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
                         join app in context.APPLICANTs 
                         on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
                        where app.APPLICANT_LogicalDelete == false
                        select app
                 );
 ..........
```